# Linked List error "Segmentation Fault" Core Dumped

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Trying on Fedora gcc the following code for a simple Linked List adding new node to the tail of the list. No error in compilation. During execution, it is showing Segmentation Fault, Core Dumped.
On MS Windows, it is working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insertion(struct Node *);
void display(struct Node *);

int main(void)
{
    struct Node *head;
    head=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;

    int choice, cont;

    do
    {
        printf("1.Insert      2.Display       3.Exit");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice==1)
        {
            insertion(head);
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            display(head);
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong choice");
        }
        printf("Continue? Press 1 otherwise 0:");
        scanf("%d",&cont);
    }while(cont==1);

    return 0;
}

void insertion(struct Node *start)
{
    int data;
    struct Node *temp=NULL;
    temp->next=NULL;
    struct Node *mnew=NULL;
    mnew->next=NULL;

    mnew=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    printf("Enter data:");
    scanf("%d",&data);

    mnew->data=data;

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=mnew;
    }
    else if(start!=NULL && start->next==NULL)
    {
        start->next=mnew;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=mnew;
    }
}

void display(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *temp=NULL;
    temp->next=NULL;    
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNothing to display!");
    }
    else if(start!=NULL && start->next==NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",start->data);
    }
    else
    {
        temp=start;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d",temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Moreover `start=mnew;` does not change `head` main value..... You should study something about pointers.

Answer (score 5):

```
head=NULL;
head->next=NULL;
```

This piece of code could never work as you cannot access or assign values to attributes of `head` if it's pointing to NULL (aka nowhere).

Comment: I have commented those second lines and now it is executing. But after inserting 3 nodes, the display function is reporting "Nothing to display!" that means the start is still NULL.

Comment: That is because you're not updating `head` - you either have to pass it into your insertion function as a reference or have that function return the new start so you can assign it to `head`

Comment: Moreover `start=mnew;` does not change `head` main value

Comment: Ok, I passed the address and it is working now. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @LPs not sure changing display is required since it doesn't modify the list

Comment: I wrote the wrong one. I was writing about insert function: `int insertion( struct Node *start )` ---to---> `int insertion( struct Node **start )`

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at e.g. these two lines from the `insertion` function:

```
struct Node *temp=NULL;
temp->next=NULL;
```

The first defines a pointer to `struct Node` and makes it be a null pointer. The very next line you dereference this null pointer, which is invalid and leads to *undefined behavior*.

You have the same problem in multiple places, both exactly like this, and also dereferencing null pointers in general.

Comment: ... or OP can use `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: Moreover `start=mnew;` does not change `head` main value

Comment: @LPs - If you are suggesting `calloc` as a shortcut to set all pointers in the structure to NULL, know that a zero bit pattern is not guaranteed to be  the value of a NULL pointer. [See this standard note on `calloc`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note296) for reference.

Comment: @LPs All bits 0 is not necessarily the same as NULL.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Well, sure but not the case here, I guess

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, sure but not the case here, I guess

Comment: @LPs - The only standard compliant way to set a pointer to a null pointer constant is by `ptr = NULL;`. No point guessing.

Comment: @StoryTeller I repeat: crystal and correct. If I really trusted that solution I would have post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may not access data using a null pointer. Thus this code snippet (and similar code snippets)

```
struct Node *head;
head=NULL;
head->next=NULL;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is invalid.

As for the function `insertion` then you have to pass the head by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the head and any changes of the copy of the head in the function will not influence on the original head.

Also if the memory allocation will failure it is desirable that the function signals about this. So instead of the return type `void` it is better to use the return type `int`.

So the function declaration can look like

```
int insertion( struct Node ** );
^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function can be defined like

```
int insertion( struct Node **start )
{
    int data;

    printf( "Enter data: " );
    scanf( "%d", &data );

    struct Node *temp = ( struct Node * )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;

        while ( *start ) start = &( *start )->next;

        *start = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function can be called the following way

```
insertion( &head );
```

The function `display` can look like

```
void display( struct Node *start )
{
    if ( start == NULL )
    {
        printf( "\nNothing to display!\n" );
    }
    else 
    {
        for ( ; start; start = start->next )
        {
            printf( "%d ", start->data );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am surprised as to why this is even working on Windows? Also any decent compiler should be able to catch this and present a warning.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comment, directing a `NULL` pointer to another `NULL` is not defined (cause a pointer should hold an address).
Now some suggestions:

1) define the struct like so:

```
typedef struct Node *node_pointer;
```

this will make it easier to define pointers for that struct.

2)

```
mnew=malloc(sizeof(*mnew)); //this is easier, and this should be before the ..->next=NULL;
```

also check if allocation succeed:

```
if (!mnew)
  return; //return something needed
```